# Considerar NULL como 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

Na seguinte consulta necessito que o valor_transacao seja considerado como 0 quando for NULL na agregação destacada, como poderá ser feito? Tentei o usar isnull mas não funcionou

```
SELECT num_empenho AS EMP, data_empenho AS DATA, nome_fornecedor AS FORNECEDOR, codigo_tipo AS CODIGO_TIPO, codigo_orgao AS CODIGO_ORGAO, valor_empenhado AS EMPENHADO, valor_anulado AS ANULADO, [3] AS LIQ_PERIODO, valor_liquidado AS LIQUID_ACUM, [5] AS PAGO_PERIODO,[7] AS PAGO_PERIODO2, valor_pago AS PAGO_ACUMUL, sld_a_liquidar AS A_LIQUIDAR, sld_a_pagar AS LIQ_A_PAGAR, cod_reduzido 
FROM ( 
         SELECT finmovem.num_transacao 
                ,finmovem.codigo_tipo 
                ,finmovem.valor_transacao 
                ,finmovem.codigo_orgao 
                ,finmovem.data_transacao
                ,finempe.cod_reduzido  
                ,finempe.data_empenho 
                ,finmovem.num_empenho 
                ,finempe.nome_fornecedor 
                ,finempe.valor_empenhado 
                ,finempe.valor_anulado 
                ,finempe.valor_pago 
                ,finempe.valor_liquidado 
                ,cast(finempe.valor_empenhado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_anulado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_liquidado as decimal(18,2)) as sld_a_liquidar 
                ,cast(finempe.valor_liquidado as decimal(18,2)) - cast(finempe.valor_pago as decimal(18,2)) as sld_a_pagar 
                ,cast(orcdotac.sld_orc_ano as decimal(18,2)) + cast(orcdotac.sld_orc_vinc as decimal(18,2)) + cast(orcdotac.sld_supl_ano as decimal(18,2)) + cast(orcdotac.sld_esp_ano as decimal(18,2)) + cast(orcdotac.sld_ext_ano as decimal(18,2)) - cast(orcdotac.sld_re_ano as decimal(18,2)) as saldo_dot_ant 
         FROM finmovem 
         INNER JOIN finempe ON 
               (finempe.num_empenho = finmovem.num_empenho) 
         INNER JOIN orcdotac ON 
               (finempe.cod_reduzido = orcdotac.cod_reduzido)  
         WHERE finmovem.codigo_tipo = 1 and finempe.codigo_tipo = 1 and finmovem.codigo_orgao = 02 and finempe.codigo_orgao = 02 and finmovem.data_transacao between '1-1-2002' and '31-12-2002' and finempe.data_empenho between '1-1-2002' and '31-12-2002'
         GROUP BY finmovem.valor_transacao, finmovem.num_transacao, finmovem.codigo_orgao, finempe.cod_reduzido, finmovem.num_empenho, finempe.data_empenho, finempe.nome_fornecedor, finempe.valor_empenhado,
         finempe.valor_anulado, finempe.valor_pago, finempe.valor_liquidado, orcdotac.sld_orc_ano, orcdotac.sld_orc_vinc, orcdotac.sld_supl_ano, orcdotac.sld_esp_ano, orcdotac.sld_ext_ano,
         orcdotac.sld_re_ano, finmovem.codigo_tipo ,finmovem.data_transacao 
     ) sq 
PIVOT (SUM(sq.valor_transacao) FOR num_transacao IN ( [3], [5], [7])) AS pt <<< nessa agregação 
ORDER BY cod_reduzido, num_empenho
```

na coluna onde o num_transacao é 3 ele retorna da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fazendo o SUM disso aí deveria retornar 4000 mas está retornando 1000.

Comment: Não sei como vc tentou implementar o `IsNull`, mas ele é realmente a saída.  
Correto seria: `PIVOT (SUM(ISNULL(SQ.VALOR_TRANSACAO,0)) FOR ....`. Sendo o `IsNull` dentro do `SUM`.

Comment: _tentei usar o isnull mas não funcionou_ Tentou como? Assim: `ISNULL(valor_transacao,0 )`?

Comment: Foi desse jeito ai mesmo que eu tentei "PIVOT (SUM(ISNULL(sq.valor_transacao,0)) FOR num_transacao IN ( [3], [5], [7])) AS pt " me retorna o seguinte erro: Mensagem 102, Nível 15, Estado 1, Linha 29
Sintaxe incorreta próxima a '('.

Comment: Pode ser alguma particularidade de sintaxe do `PIVOT`. Nesse caso, resolve para você se você usar o `ISNULL` no select interno: `(...), ISNULL(finmovem.valor_transacao, 0) as valor_transacao (...)`

Comment: não funcionou, ele não tá fazendo a soma corretamente

Answer (score 1):

Use [COALESCE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Essa função do SQL recebe uma lista de n parâmetros e retorna o primeiro valor não nulo que encontrar. Abaixo segue um pequeno exemplo:

```
create table tabela_exemplo
(
   descricao varchar(20) not null
  ,valorA decimal(18,2) null
  ,valorB decimal(18,2) null
)

GO

insert into tabela_exemplo
(descricao, valorA, valorB)
values
 ('A e B não nulos', 1,2)
,('A e B não nulos', 3,4)
,('A e B não nulos', 5,6)
,('A nulos B com valor', null,8)
,('A nulos B com valor', null,10)
,('A nulos B com valor', null,12)
,('tudo nulo', null,null)
,('tudo nulo', null,null)
,('tudo nulo', null,null)

GO

select te.descricao, te.valorA, te.valorB, coalesce(te.valorA, te.valorB, 42) as [Esta coluna nunca retorna null]
from dbo.tabela_exemplo te

/* Exemplo com aggregate */ 
select te.descricao, sum(te.valorA), sum(te.valorB), sum(coalesce(te.valorA, te.valorB, 42)) as [Este somatório nunca retorna null]
from dbo.tabela_exemplo te
group by te.descricao
```

Resultado:

```
descricao            valorA  valorB  Esta coluna nunca retorna null
-------------------- ------- ------- ------------------------------
A e B não nulos      1.00     2.00    1.00
A e B não nulos      3.00     4.00    3.00
A e B não nulos      5.00     6.00    5.00
A nulos B com valor  NULL     8.00    8.00
A nulos B com valor  NULL    10.00   10.00
A nulos B com valor  NULL    12.00   12.00
tudo nulo            NULL     NULL   42.00
tudo nulo            NULL     NULL   42.00
tudo nulo            NULL     NULL   42.00

(9 linhas afetadas)

descricao            Sum(A) Sum(B) Este somatório nunca retorna null
-------------------- ------ ------ ---------------------------------
A e B não nulos       9.00  12.00    9.00
A nulos B com valor   NULL  30.00   30.00
tudo nulo             NULL   NULL  126.00


Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(3 linhas afetadas)
```